# Youtube Player Iframe, sound with no video on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, video, youtube

I'm using YT Player API to create a multiple iframe youtube videos within slider the first video is called after 'onYouTubeIframeAPIReady' the next videos appear when I click the next button which is working as it should. 
but when I try to play the video on firefox some videos goes black with voice only,
I discovered that the videos goes with the black screen try to use flash not the html5 feature.
some times it's work but I can't control the video to stop it.

Here's below the link
http://www.thesevenlayers.net/mi7/slider.html?sec=&node=17

Comment: have u installed adobe flash player in ur system...

Comment: Sure latest version.
It's working well on chrome/safari

Comment: i am able to play yt videos in ff latest version is wat i have..

Comment: can you hard refresh the browse and check again and test if you can stop the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2 days Working on this issue I discovered where is the problem.

I was using idangerous Swiper for the sliding content so.

idangerous Swiper using CSS3 transform prevents the controls of the youtube video from being displayed and also prevent the full-screen option of it.

Setting the `backface-visibility` property on `.swiper-container` will prevent the full-screen transform CSS on `.swiper-wrapper` class prevent the controls of the youtube and make many other issues like the black screen, Audio playing without video etc...

so I think you should put in your consideration to change the idangerous Swiper if you want the youtube video to play properly.