# Youtube iframe loaded by API plays audio, no video

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a carousel of images that when a button is clicked, it loads a youtube video using the Javascript youtube API. This works  for most instances. On a MAC in Firefox, there are two videos that this does not work for. The video loads and you hear the sound, but there is no video and the controls inside the iframe are not clickable.

Here is the code that I use to load the video:

```
try{
    $this.player = new YT.Player($slide.children('.iframeWrapper').children('.player').get(0), {
        height: (parseInt(videoHeight) - 15),
        width: videoWidth,
        videoId: videoId,
        playVars: { 'rel': 0, 'controls': 1, 'playsinline':1, 'start': $this.pausedAt, 'html5': 1, 'autoplay': 1, 'wmode': 'opaque' },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError': onPlayerError
        }
    });
} catch(err){

}
```

From the searching I have done, I have seen that there was bug similar to what I am experiencing, but it sounds like it has been fixed.

Im on FF 35.0.1 and OSX Mavrick.

These images are in a carousel and for the carousel im using [1](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)slick.js.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680139/youtube-player-iframe-sound-with-no-video-on-firefox

Comment: @martialdidit I tried not using `transform` to move my carousel and it still does not play the video.